# must be owner of function when creating a function in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to debug an instance where I try to create a function with a special role `"myrole"` and the operation fails with

> ERROR:  must be owner of function refresh_view

Other functions can be created successfully — it's only this single function that is failing.

```
SET ROLE to "myrole";

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION refresh_view(schema_name text, table_name text)
RETURNS void
SECURITY DEFINER
AS $$
DECLARE sql text;
BEGIN
sql := 'REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW ' || quote_ident(schema_name) || '.' || quote_ident(table_name) || ' with data';
EXECUTE sql;
RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: because you try to replace it?..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The function already exists and is owned by a different role.

Only the owner or a superuser can `DROP` and `ALTER` objects, and the same applies for `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION` if the function already exists.

Comment: It had made it to `template1` for some inexplicable reason. Probably PEBKAC as per ususal.